# PHP add line in between two lines in textfile

Tags: php

I need to insert a line in a textfile between two other lines:

1: 30-12:32 1

2: 30-12:34 1

3: 30-12:35 1

For an example I need to insert a line between 1 and 2 which says 30-12:34  0.
I have the code to calculate what needs to be inserted by looking at the previous number but I need help inserting the text.
Thank you

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: Splitting the entire text file and then putting it back together however the file is every big and so this is not practical.

Comment: I know the line number which I want to insert is after and before if this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this and then

```
function replaceInFile($what, $with, $file){
   $buffer = "";
   $fp = file($file);
   foreach($fp as $line){
      $buffer .= preg_replace("|".$what."[A-Za-z_.]*|", $what.$with, $line);
   }
   fclose($fp);
   echo $buffer;
   file_put_contents($file, $buffer);
}
```

and then enter what as the line just before it in text and with as what you want after it.